# Identify buttons on click?

Tags: vb.net

So here's what I have:

Code that makes buttons when you click the button "New Button" (Button1).

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ActionsMade = ActionsMade + 1

        Dim actionButton = New Windows.Forms.Button
        ActionContainer.Controls.Add(actionButton)
        actionButton.Text = "New Action " + ActionsMade.ToString
        actionButton.Width = 107
        actionButton.Height = 56

        AddHandler actionButton.Click, AddressOf OnActionButtonClick
    End Sub
```

When you click the buttons that were created, it shows an input box, where you type what you want to rename the button to.

```
Sub OnActionButtonClick()
    If IsRenaming Then
        Dim renameTo As String
        renameTo = InputBox("Rename ActionButton To:")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Action started! Not renaming")
    End If
End Sub
```

The only problem is, I have no way to identify between these buttons.

tl;dr:

- I created buttons programmatically
- I want to rename them
- I don't know how to identify between these buttons and rename them individually

Comment: Give each button a unique name: `actionButton.Name = button1;` etc.  Then you can search the container for buttons that have that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more concise and includes a referencable button name (eg *Button_03*):

```
Private Sub MakeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MakeButton.Click

    Static ActionsMade As Integer = 0
    ActionsMade += 1
    ActionContainer.Controls.Add(New Button With {
        .Name = $"Button_{ActionsMade:00}",
        .Text = $"New Action {ActionsMade:00}",
        .Size = New Size(107, 56),
        .Location = New Point(100, 250 + 25 * ActionsMade)
    })
    AddHandler ActionContainer.Controls($"Button_{ActionsMade:00}").Click, AddressOf OnActionButtonClick
End Sub
```

Note that in the above code I haven't actually defined a new button *per se*, just *New-ed* it within the `Controls.Add()` statement, and then used the generated button name to add the event handler.

Another way would be declare the button as an independent object and then add it:

```
Dim actionButton As New Button With {
    .Name = $"Button_{ActionsMade:00}",
    .Text = $"New Action {ActionsMade:00}",
    .Size = New Size(107, 56),
    .Location = New Point(100, 250 + 25 * ActionsMade)
}
ActionContainer.Controls.Add(actionButton)
AddHandler actionButton.Click, AddressOf OnActionButtonClick
```

Other notes:

1. Use of a `Static` `ActionsMade` integer variable which retains its value between calls. This could also be a module-wide variable and removed from the `MakeButton_Click` Sub.
2. Use of string interpolation in assigning the button's `Name` and `Text` properties according to a formated version of the `ActionsMade` value.
3. Use of button properties `Size` and `Location`.
4. Automatic increment of button vertical position based on the value of `ActionsMade`.

Regarding your Action Button event handler, it should look like this:

```
Private Sub OnActionButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    If ActionStarted Then
        MessageBox.Show("Action started! Not renaming.")
    Else
        CType(sender, Button).Text = InputBox("Rename ActionButton To:")
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that I've checked for a started Action rather than a renaming in progress but that's just an illustration of an alternative approach. Note also that you don't need to know the name of the button to change its properties.